# What size images should i put in drawable-mdpi folder

Tags: android

I have three device with resolution 320x480, 1024 x 600, 1280 x 800. out of these three devices two are tablets. Now each of these devices has a density 160dp, as a result of this, all of this device takes images from the drawable-mdpi folder. Now my question is what will be the size of the image should I put inside this drawable-mdpi folder? So that it looks good in all of these devices.

Answer (score 3):

//for phone you need to put in

`drawable-mdpi`

//for tablet you need to put in

`drawable large-mdpi`

**NOTE:** this large-mdi drawble is enough for 10' inch device 
for few images your can use `drawable-xlarge-mdpi` like background with 1280*800 or splash screen..

an you can create different layout to adjust the view or arranging the drawables as

```
layout-large and layout-xlarge
```

Comment: In my case for storing layout i have used layout-ldpi, layout-hdpi, layout-mdpi, layout-xhdpi folder, Similarly for storing image i have used drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi folder. So it is correct way of doing or not..

Answer (score 1):

put `320x480` size images in drawable-mdpi folder.

- [See here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Comment: ok...but the images are strech in tablets simlarly for layout also..it takes layout from layout-mdpi folder...as a result of which the look chages in all devices