# Android different screen support

Tags: android

I want some help  of different screen support. Also want to know the advantage of 9 Patch image over .png image use in the drawable folder.

Comment: Not working means what it is doing?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11558724/1012284

Comment: And i have also put the images(1024*600) for tablet in android mdpi folder.its wrong

Comment: when i put images(1024*600) in drawable-mdpi then it is working fine in android 7 inch tab but in the same time the view is change in Android Galaxy ace. It also takes images from mdpi folder not from hdpi. Though in hdpi there are also images (480*800). If i do not put images(1024*600) in mdpi the it is working fine in android mobile.

Comment: I strongly recommend you go through this and give it a quick read. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html Shouldn't take more than 30 minutes to an hour, but you'll get a much better grasp of how Android works to support different screen sizes and the (awesome) tools it gives developers. LE: Or just go for [Dymitro's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1056263/dmytro-danylyk) answer if you need a really quick fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is not guaranteed that tablet will come with `hdpi` density screens (especially cheap 7"). Resolution and density are two **separated** beasts, even they look like come together. Please read this article [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). I **strongly** recommend the whole one, however section "Using configuration qualifiers" shall help you addressing your issue, as instead of relying on density, you could consider putting your resources in resolution qualified resource folder instead (depending on target API, as these appeared in HC)

Comment: Can't see why on earth this was downvoted so putting one back in to restore the natural balance of the Androidverse.  To add to this, there is nothing stopping me from creating an Android device with a 1 inch screen and a really high DPI and a 10 inch screen with a really low DPI.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use this directory structure:

```
drawable-mdpi // 320 x 480 - Galaxy Ace
drawable-hdpi // 480 x 800 - Desire, Nexus One
drawable-xhdpi // 720 x 1280 - Sony Xperia S, Galaxy S
drawable-large-nodpi // 800 x 1280 - Nexus 7
drawable-xlarge-nodpi // Galaxy Tab, Xoom
```

Note: **nodpi** is necessary to prevent resources scaling.